# Show that $\frac {MA}{MB}\cdot \frac {MC}{MD}=\frac {NA}{NB}\cdot \frac {NC}{ND}$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let ABCD a quadrilateral and $AB\cap CD$={M}, $AD\cap BC$={N}.

Show that $\frac {MA}{MB}\cdot \frac {MC}{MD}=\frac {NA}{NB}\cdot \frac {NC}{ND}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $K$ in $MA$ such $DK$ parallel to $BC$ and 
$L$ in $NC$ so $DL$ parallel to $AB$. 
so $BKLD$ parallelogram so $KD=BL$

Also $AS$ parallel to $BC$

so $\frac{MC}{MD}=\frac{MB}{MK}$ and

$\frac{NA}{ND}=\frac{NB}{NL}$

$\frac{MA*MC}{MB*MD}=\frac{NA*NC}{ND*NB}\Leftrightarrow
\frac{MA}{MK}=\frac{NC}{NL}\Leftrightarrow \frac{AS}{KD}=\frac{NC}{BL+NB}\Leftrightarrow\frac{KD+NB}{KD}=\frac{NC}{AS}
\Leftrightarrow 1+\frac{NB}{KD}=\frac{NC}{AS}=\frac{NA+AD}{AD}=1+\frac{NA}{AD}$

So $\frac{NA}{AD}=\frac{NB}{KD}$ which is true